# Java: Calling a method by reflection in a functional interface

Tags: java, reflection, interface, functional-programming

does anyone know, if i can invoke a method by reflection in the body of a functional interface?

I want to return a predicate. So the typical syntax would be for example

```
Predicate<Data> pred = data -> data.getVar1().equals("foobar");
```

But in my special case neither the class nor the method to call is known since it's variable.

So I wanted to get something like this:

```
Method method = Class.forName("Data").getMethod("getVar1", (Class[]) null);
Predicate<T> pred = data -> 
                  ((String) method.invoke(data, (Object[]) null)).equals("foobar");
```

But Eclipse says: "Not handled TargetInvocationException". So I surrounded it with try-catch, but Eclipse shows already the same message.

Does anyone have a clue for me?

Comment: encapsulate method.invoke to method =)

Comment: What’s the relationship between the dynamically loaded class `Data` and the compile-time type `T`? It doesn’t look right that a function which expects its argument to be of type `Data` claims to accept arguments of type `T`…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
    Predicate<T> pred = data -> {
        try {
            return ((String) method.invoke(data, (Object[]) null)).equals("foobar");
        } catch (IllegalAccessException illegalAccessException) {
//  
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException illegalArgumentException) {
//
        } catch (InvocationTargetException invocationTargetException) {
//
        }
        return false;
    };
```

Comment: The cast to `String` is obsolete, you can simply invoke `equals` as that method is already defined in `Object`. Further, it’s enough to catch `ReflectiveOperationException`, that will cover all necessary checked exceptions. Also, mind the varargs nature of the `invoke`; you can simply say `method.invoke(data)`. Putting it all together: `Predicate<T> pred = data -> { try { return method.invoke(data).equals("foobar"); } catch(ReflectiveOperationException ex) { throw new AssertionError(ex); } }`

Comment: The question was about unhandled exceptions. I took topic starter's snippet.